# Folder inside the right folder, C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, directory

When my program runs, i want it to create a folder into the right country folder. If the error is from country 1, it should be put into that folder. Now it only creates new folders in the same path and not into "Country1" path.

- Example:
- How it is now: C:\Country1 Failure 2014-1-21
- How it should be: C:\Country1\Country1 Failure 2014-1-21

What am i doing wrong?

```
    #region Failure Folder Creation
        string failureDir = string.Empty;
        failureDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Source\\";
        try
        {

            string failureDirToday = string.Empty;
            if (metaDataXmlPath.Contains("Country1"))
                failureDir = failureDir + "\\Country1 Failure";
            else if (metaDataXmlPath.Contains("Country2"))
                failureDir = "\\Country2 Failure";
            else if (metaDataXmlPath.Contains("Country3"))
                failureDir = "\\Country3 Failure";
            failureDirToday = failureDir + " " + todayMoveDate;

            if (!Directory.Exists(failureDir))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(failureDir);

            if (!Directory.Exists(failureDirToday))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(failureDirToday);
        }
```

Comment: Can you just log/debug `failureDir` varible before any operations with files? If it is not what you expected, find out what's wrong

Comment: Best practice is to use `System.IO.Path.Combine(failureDir, "Country1 Failure")` rather than `failureDir + "\\Country1 Failure";`

Comment: This just added a 2014-1-21 folder into the main structure

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you create the `Country1` subfolder.

I'd simply change

```
if (metaDataXmlPath.Contains("Country1"))
    failureDir = failureDir + "\\Country1 Failure";
```

into

```
if (metaDataXmlPath.Contains("Country1"))
    failureDir = failureDir + "Country1\\Country1 Failure";
```

(This is just the most simple solution. When working with paths, I would stick to the static [`path.combine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx)-method instead of string concatenations.)

---

Let's go through your code and see what happens:

```
failureDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Source\\";
```

`failureDir` is now `C:\Source`.

We suppose the code runs into the first if-branch:

```
failureDir = failureDir + "\\Country1 Failure";
```

`failureDir` is now `C:\Source\Country1 Failure`

After all the if-elses theres one final statement:

```
failureDirToday = failureDir + " " + todayMoveDate;
```

So `failureDirToday` is `C:\Source\Country1 Failure 2014-1-21`. This is the same result as you get and as I stated in the beginning: you simply don't create any subfolder named `Country1`.

Comment: Thanks for great help and explanation of my dizzyness in coding. Its getting close but now it is adding two folders: Country1 Failure AND Country1 Failure 2014-1-21 into the main Country 1 failure folder.. haha. I only need the last one and then all is good :)

Comment: @Lebowski Then you have to remove `Directory.CreateDirectory(failureDir);` as this is the one which creates to folder without the date.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not sure what you are trying to achieve by calling *AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory*. this will return the folder from which the application is ran, and not C: or any other root folder.
   I also don't see why you attach *Source* folder to it, but maybe that is part of what you wanted to do.
2. You should use Path.Combine in order to concatenate the folder names and create a hierarchy. 
   In your example you are creating 2 different folders, one with and one without the date.
   What you should do instead, is something like

   ```
   if(metaDataXmlPath.Contains("Country1"))
   {
        string errorSourceName = "Country1";
        failureDir = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(failureDir, errorSourceName), String.Format("{0} {1}", errorSourceName, todayMoveDate));
   }
   ```

   and now you can create the *failureDir* **only**, and this will create the entire hierarchy.

   I'm adding a code sample of how your code should look after the change

   ```
   string failureDir = string.Empty;
   failureDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Source\\";
   try
   {

       string failureDirToday = string.Empty;
       if(metaDataXmlPath.Contains("Country1"))
       {
            string errorSourceName = "Country1";
            failureDir = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(failureDir, errorSourceName), String.Format("{0} {1}", errorSourceName, todayMoveDate));
       }
       else if (metaDataXmlPath.Contains("Country2"))
       {
            string errorSourceName = "Country2";
            failureDir = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(failureDir, errorSourceName), String.Format("{0} {1}", errorSourceName, todayMoveDate));
       }
       else if (metaDataXmlPath.Contains("Country3"))
       {
            string errorSourceName = "Country3";
            failureDir = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(failureDir, errorSourceName), String.Format("{0} {1}", errorSourceName, todayMoveDate));
       }
       // Notice the eliminated line here

       // This is where we actually create the folder
       if (!Directory.Exists(failureDir))
           Directory.CreateDirectory(failureDir);

       // Notice the eliminated line here
   }
   ```

Comment: This code created two subfolders inside the Country1. Danmark Failure 2014-1-21 AND Danmark Failure 2014-1-21 2014-1-21

Comment: Please see my edit. and delete the folders from the Source directory before you run the code.

Comment: This worked out perfectly now, only one question left: If i run this tomorrow, will it add Cuntry1 Failure 2014-1-22 into the Country1 folder then?

Comment: In your example you didn't show how you extract the date value to todayMoveDate variable. the correct way to do it would be to call DateTime.Today and format it to the date format that you would like. if you have the correct date then yes, it will add it under the correct folder. if you find my answer helpful please up vote it, thanx

Comment: My friend, i wish i could vote up your treat but i still need 5 more points. But i will do it as soon as possible.. Thanks for great help :)